# offsetLeft Value Changes Unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, dom, onload, offset, xpathnodeiterator

Consider the following code segment:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'foobar.html';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

iframe.onload = function () {
    var nodeIterator = iframe.contentDocument.createNodeIterator(
        iframe.contentDocument.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
        { acceptNode: function (node) {
            if (node.hasAttribute('id')) {
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
            } else {
                return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP;
            }
        }}, false),
    currentNode, someArray = [];

    while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
        // Calculate offsetLeft
        someArray.push({
            id: currentNode.id,
            left: (function () {
                var a = currentNode, b = 0;
                while (a) {
                    b += a.offsetLeft;
                    a = a.offsetParent;
                }
                return b;
            }())
        });

        // On element click, log offsetLeft after calculating again
        currentNode.onclick = function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            var a = this, b = 0;
            while (a) {
                b += a.offsetLeft;
                a = a.offsetParent;
            }
            console.log(b);
        };
    }
};
```

The issue I'm having is this:  For some of the elements, the `offsetLeft` calculation is different the second time it's calculated.  Using Google Chrome's inspector, I can see that the second time the calculation occurs `offsetLeft` is always accurate.

The `offsetLeft` calculation done during Node Iteration is wrong for some elements, but consistently (the value is always the same across page refreshes).

I'm wondering if anyone has any insights as to why this is the case.  I've been thinking that `iframe.onload` actually fires before the elements in its `contentDocument` have finished loading completely, causing some elements to be further left or right initially.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but in this code: `var a = currentNode, b = 0;while (a) {...`, won't the while condition always be true? Also, your IIFE appears to have a syntax error. Towards the end, you have `}())`, which I **think** should be `})()`

Comment: @Asad `})()` and `}())` are actually equivalent.  Also, the condition for `a` won't always be true because in the loop `a` is continually reassigned to the `offsetParent`.  Eventually, `offsetParent` will be undefined.

Comment: Having the same issue.